# Event not working in MySQL v5.5.30

Tags: mysql, events

I have been trying to create an event within a MySQL Database (v5.5.30). I followed the syntax from the MySQL documentation and the event seems to create just fine without errors. However, it does not appear as if the event is actually executing. Here is the syntax ...

```
CREATE EVENT `Restock_Traders_Test`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
ENDS '2013-07-31 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO update traders_data set qty = 25 where qty = 0;
```

Though the event is set to fire every minute I am only doing this for testing. I keep checking the table to see if the quantity is updated but it does not appear to be updated. Does anyone see anything wrong with my syntax? Is there something I missed?

Below is the results of running the `SHOW EVENTS` command

```
dayz_epoch  Restock_Traders_Test    myusername@%    SYSTEM  RECURRING   NULL    1   MINUTE  2013-07-30 14:20:10 2013-07-31 00:00:00 ENABLED 0   latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [enable the event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html), which is `OFF` by default:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

You can see if it's running by executing `SHOW PROCESSLIST\G` and seeing if you have a thread with the user `event_scheduler`.

Although the default is `OFF`, it's possible for the configuration to set it to `DISABLED`, which means you can't set it to `ON` at runtime. If that's the case, you'll need to change the setting in your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks you very much. That was it. `SHOW PROCESSLIST\G` gave me an error but if I removed the `\G` it showed me the list. As you mentioned all I had to do was `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` and it was enabled.

Comment: `\G` is understood by the `mysql` command-line client. I guess you're using a different client! Glad you sorted it. Don't forget to configure your `my.cnf` or `my.ini` file so the event scheduler is enabled next time MySQL restarts.